# Excel VBA: Copy Sheet2(A2) to Sheet1(Bx) When Change Is Made To Sheet1(Cx)

Tags: excel, vba

Apologies for what will likely seem easy but I'm fairly new and I'm stuck.  I'm reading the cells in the "Master" Sheet, Column C, for certain value changes; when the change is made I need copy contents (it's a hyperlink) found in A2 on the "Codes" sheet back to the "Master" Column B to the cell adjacent to the one where the change was just made.

I've got the part to check for changes and copy the cell but I can't get the paste part of it.

```
If Intersect(Target, Range("C:C")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
If Target = "Decomm" Then
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Sheets("Codes").Range("A2").Copy
    Sheets("Master").Activate
```

Thanks for any help you can offer.

Comment: Have you tried using `Sheets("Codes").Range("A2").Copy Sheets("Master").RANGE` to copy across?

Comment: Thanks for responding.  I had tried this but for some reason gives an error "Wrong number of arguments or invalid property assignment".  I am sure it's something I have done/not done.  But I do appreciate your taking the time to respond.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean like so? This will copy A2 to the cell to the left of the one changed. Or do you mean column B on a different sheet?

```
If Intersect(target, Range("C:C")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
If target = "Decomm" Then
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Sheets("Codes").Range("A2").Copy target.Offset(, -1)
   'line below instead if a different sheet 
   'Sheets("Codes").Range("A2").Copy sheets("Master").range(target.Offset(, -1).address)
End If
```

Comment: Thank you so much.  I was trying to copy A2 to the cell to the left of the one that changed.  This worked like a charm.  I appreciate it so much.

Comment: My pleasure. Perhaps you'd be so good as to accept the answer.